# Shared memory containers between a 32 and 64 bit processes

Tags: shared-memory

Is it possible to share a stl container (for e.g std::map) via shared memory between a 32 and 64 bit process ?

Comment: Possible? Probably... Simple/easy? A good idea? Most likely not...

Comment: To begin with everything was 32 bit. Now a constraint on addressable memory necessitates a move to 64 bit. However what makes this difficult is non availability of several 64 bit safe libraries. And that leads to this situation. Exploring this as one of the alternatives.